# A list of obtainable plants that need very little light?

Tags: indoors, moss

I have just moved into my new flat. And again, I'm noticing that plants make *the* difference between a place feeling rather dull and dead or being nice to hang out at.

So here is my central question:

**Can somebody provide me with a list of plants that grow with (very) little light?**

This is not the darkest apartment, but it's not exactly sunny, either.

More specific details:

I'm particularly interested in plants that would grow in my bathroom, which only has a small (maybe 8 inches high, 1 foot 6 inches wide) **indoor** window that  admits some daylight which comes from the wall with all the outdoor windows across.
Of course, humidity is high in the bathroom as well, so the plant should also be ok with that.
On the bright side, it's not too cold there/ I could keep it a little warmer - wouldn't want to keep it tropical though, to be honest.

Since this is not a purely theoretical question, the plants you mention are required to be somewhat obtainable through normal outlets.

Some people might now scream "Oh noes! **No** plant will ever grow in this dark cave harboring you and thoust will perish slowly", but somehow, my hopes are still high about the plant growing part...

I'm thinking about moss, so there is at least some plant that might make it in my bathroom.

But I also can't shake the hope that there must be a couple of other plants used to growing in darker forest places below thick branchwork, where it might always be quite dark.

Any ideas?

Edit: I would also be glad to hear what problems the respective plants might entail (any particular bugs or hardships in keeping the plant from wilting off etc.).